# Strange incident of Controller#update not updating model at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a strange case. Neither my co-worker nor me can figure out why it doesn't work. Perhaps someone had a similar case or can spot whatever it is we are overlooking. Here's what we have:

Rails 3.2.6
mysql Database

We have a `Comment` model. Like this:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: comments
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  username     :string(255)
#  realname     :string(255)
#  email        :string(255)
#  title        :string(255)
#  content      :text
#  comment_date :datetime
#  article_id   :string(255)
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null
#  rating       :float
#

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :realname, :email, :title, :content, :comment_date, :article_id, :rating
  belongs_to :article, class_name: Goldencobra::Article, foreign_key: "article_id"
end
```

I tried it with `attr_accessible` and without to no effect.
I created a `CommentsController` like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token
  protect_from_forgery only: [:index]

  def index
    @article = Goldencobra::Article.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @article.comments
    respond_to do |format|
      format.rss
    end
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.save!
    flash[:notice] = 'Comment was successfully created.'
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    render :action => :new
  end

  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    if @comment && @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
      render text: "Success", layout: false
    else
      render text: "No success", layout: false
    end
  end
end
```

What I want to to is use the update action to update the comment model. Like what we do every single time. Piece of cake…
Only, it doesn't update. Here is how I test for the update:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CommentsController do

  def do_create
    @article = Goldencobra::Article.create(title: "Testartikel", article_type: "Default Show")
    post :create, :comment => {username: "johnny",
                               realname: "John Doe",
                               email: "johnny@gmail.com",
                               title: "Great title",
                               content: "What an awesome article.",
                               article_id: @article.id,
                               rating: 3.4}
  end

  it "should update a comment" do
    do_create
    put :update, id: Comment.first.id, comment: {title: "New great title"}
    Comment.first.title.should eql("New great title")
  end
end
```

I tried the same thing with updating via a REST-client (Rested.app on OS X)
[image: Restful try params]
[image: Restful try response]

I always get a "Success" response. `.update_attributes()` always succeeds. Thing is: It changes nothing. Here's the console log from the restful try:

```
Started PUT "/comments/10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-07-18 12:35:13 +0200
Processing by CommentsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"comment"=>{"title"=>"neuer test"}, "id"=>"10"}
  Comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`id` = 10 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

This is what it looks like, when I try the same thin in the rails console:

```
1.9.2p290 :017 > Comment.last.update_attributes(title: "test 2")
  Comment Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` ORDER BY `comments`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.5ms)  UPDATE `comments` SET `title` = 'test 2', `updated_at` = '2012-07-18 09:48:39' WHERE `comments`.`id` = 10
   (3.4ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

What's missing is `UPDATE`comments`SET`title`= 'test 2',`updated_at`= '2012-07-18 09:48:39' WHERE`comments`.`id`= 10`. Can anybody tell me why my controller does not update the model?

Thank you.

Comment: My goodness, I'd like to print this question and put it into frame - haven't seen anything as thoroughly formatted. Sorry for pointless comment though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not trying to update 'title' to its old value? I know it sounds stupid, but sometimes i am overlooking something obvious and need another person to point me some obvious thing.

Comment: Nice idea. Unfortunately the rspec test makes sure a new value is set. It's expecting "New great title" but gets "Great title".

Comment: Ofc. I focused on your 'restful try' and missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your rest client is missing one parameter in your params hash:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gzC0IKScOUu+RBacL1YREpe4aE4KgnD0lqOgMhwRKVA="
```

it is authenticity_token. It is place in Rails app forms as:

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="gzC0IKScOUu+RBacL1YREpe4aE4KgnD0lqOgMhwRKVA=" />
```

So you cannot update a record from some other app (as you are trying to do). You can skip this before filter with:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

in your controller.

Comment: that is exactly what I am doing. Please see my controller. The skip_before_filter is there.

Comment: Oh, It is really there, sorry for my temporary blindness. I saw parameters hash from console log and thought 'That's it!'. Ok, try hardcoding parameters with changed `:title`. If it works try `binding.pry` after `@comment` object is assigned. Then investigate params hash from the pry console.